# .NET: Blog post on GUID?

Tags: .net, guid

I once read a blog post by a dev at Microsoft about the anatomy--what individual pieces of data are combined--of a System.Guid. Does anyone have the link? I'm not finding it by googling.

Comment: Instead of asking for the MSDN or blog link, why not just ask what features are used to make up a guid?

Comment: I could, but I don't think anyone knows. I'm specifically talking about a .NET Guid object. If someone does, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this one?

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Note that the .NET Guid type is no different from a native GUID type.